# Xamarin.iOS CS8370 Feature 'range operator' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, c#-8.0, c#-7.3

I'm trying to follow one of the tutorial for Xamarin application.
My VS is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.5
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.5+31729.503
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

After a while, I've reached the chapter, which produces the following code (in iOS project):

```
foreach (PHAsset asset in results[startIndex..endIndex])
{
    var filename = (NSString)asset.ValueForKey((NSString)"filename");             
    RequestImage(photos, asset, filename, options);
}
return photos;
```

this code [startIndex..endIndex] throws an error: Error CS8370  Feature 'range operator' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

Actions done so far:
in the C# project I've modified the project file:
a) initial code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

b) I've changed the  to 8.0

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

c) I've changed the  to netcoreapp3.0

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

d) My C# project -> Properties -> Application
the Target framework is showing .NET Standard 2.1, I've clicked the 'Install other frameworks...' in the lookup -> this forwarded me to the "Download .NET SDKs for Visual Studio" (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk) - I've downloaded the .NET Core 3.1 (Runtime (Windows))

e) if add this piece of code (#error version) to the class, it shows this info:

CS8304  Compiler version: '3.11.0-4.21403.6 (ae1fff34)'. Language version: 7.3.

So, the question is - what I need to do to force the compiler uses the 8.0 LangVersion?

Comment: You can't (currently) change xamarin to anything newer than .netstandard2.1. But that should automatically support c# 8, so the error is puzzling. First, make sure Visual Studio is up to date. Then, I recommend creating a new xamarin project, and testing c# 8 features in that. If that works, then it may be easiest to add all your source files to that new project. Alternatively, compare its csproj to yours - there must be some difference.

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve ! Thank you for this suggestion.
I've updated my Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 from Version 16.11.5 to 16.11.17.
Apart from that, I’ve created another Xamarin project (TestApp) and added just one interface and one class (which actually being causing an error in my original project), but the error is still there (CS8370 Feature 'range operator' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater). But, I’ve discovered one interesting thing:

When I created a TestApp Solution (to check your suggestion) the structure of my Xamarin project is:

Comment: Solution(TestApp)
TestApp 
TestApp.Andriod
TestApp.IOS

The Project file was:
**<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>**

I’ve added a folder Models to the TestApp project and created a class Photo (in the Models folder)
Solution(TestApp)
TestApp 
 Models
  Photo
TestApp.Andriod
TestApp.IOS
Then, in the TestApp project I created an interface IPhotoImporter

Comment: The Solution is:
TestApp 
 Model
  Photo
IPhotoImporter
TestApp.Andriod
TestApp.IOS
**public interface IPhotoImporter
    {
        public Task<ObservableCollection<Photo>> Get(
            int start,
            int count,
            Quality quality = Quality.Low);
        public Task<ObservableCollection<Photo>> Get(
            List<string> filenames,
            Quality quality = Quality.Low);
    }**
At this moment, the compiler has thrown an error:
CS8703 The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item in C# 7.3. Please use language version '8.0' or greater.

Comment: I've modified the project file by adding **<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>** and error has gone. BUT THAN - I created a class PhotoImporter in TesApp.IOS (**public class PhotoImporter : IPhotoImporter**) and the error has popped up again:

CS8370 Feature 'range operator' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

The IPhotoImporter is located in TesApp project, but the PhotoImporter class is located in TesApp.IOS project. Seems like the LangVersion tag is working for the TesApp project but not for the TesApp.IOS

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I would highly appreciate for any idea

Comment: Have you tried to add  `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` instead of `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` in the property group?